Descent of $G$-invariant formal system of parameters using GAGF
Let $R=(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a comm local regular ring of char $\neq 2$ (ie $2 \neq 0$ in $R$) with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of (Krull) dimension $2$, ie $R$ admits system of parameters $x,y \in \mathfrak{m} -\mathfrak{m}^2$ generating $\mathfrak{m}$. Assume $G= \langle g \rangle :=\Bbb Z/2$ acts on $R$ as nontrivial local ring involution (ie (ie $g: R \to R$ local ring homom).
Let $\widehat{R}=(\widehat{R},\widehat{\mathfrak{m}})$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of $R$ and the action by $G$ extends to $\widehat{R}$. We have canon faithfully flat local map $\phi: R \to \widehat{R}$.
Assume we can find system of parameters $\widehat{x}, \widehat{y} \in \widehat{\mathfrak{m}}$ such that $g(\widehat{x})= \widehat{x}$ and $g(\widehat{y})= -\widehat{y}$.  / / / (*)
Question: Does this property "descends" back to $R$, ie does this assure that $R$ admits system of parameters $x,y$ such that $g(x)=x, g(y)=-y$?
Remark(s): I think the statement about existence of system of parameters $x,y$ holds even without loosing one word about the completion, if one instead assumes weaker statement that there exist parameters x,y with
$$  g(x)=x + \mathfrak{m}^2, g(y)=-y +\mathfrak{m}^2  $$
Then one can construct modified $x', y'$ with desired property setting explicitly
$$ x':= x+g(x) , \ \ \ y':= y - g(y)  $$
Note, using this approach I not lost any word about completion.
But the nature of the concern of the question above is if the existence of such $x,y$ can also be derived (non constructively) as pure formal consequence from existence of formal parameters $\widehat{x}, \widehat{y} \in \widehat{\mathfrak{m}}$ satisfying (*)?
In other words, if this claim is a pure formal consequence of GAGF, without need "to make hand durty" on an explicit construction?
Motivation: Extend this machinery to general finite cyclic $G=C_n$, where we cannot / or it becomes much harder to construct explicit solution, so the question is really about the technique itself, not the truthness of this "obvious" result.
